# background image doesn't appear full screen on mobile

Tags: html, css, background-image, responsive

I am trying to set an image as a background, but it doesn't fit at mobiles:

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Is there another way to make it without changing wallpapers with a @media attribute?

My HTML and CSS:

```css
    body { 
/* Location of the image */
  background-image: url(../img/background.jpg);
  
  /* Background image is centered vertically and horizontally at all times */
  background-position: center center;
  
  /* Background image doesn't tile */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  /* Background image is fixed in the viewport so that it doesn't move when 
     the content's height is greater than the image's height */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  
  /* This is what makes the background image rescale based
     on the container's size */
  background-size: cover;
  
  /* Set a background color that will be displayed
     while the background image is loading */
  background-color: #464646;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>ALOOOU</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use body{height:100vh;}

Comment: this works but now i receive scrollbar on desktop view :|

Answer (score 3):

Add a viewport height to your body for mobile like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        height:100vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using it as a full width background on the html tag:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

body tag only to 100x100px  .this img tag full of window.

```css
body { 
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
/* normal body */
 }
.CanvasImg {
        background-position: center center;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        border: 0;
        background: url("http://sendeyim.net/uploads/resim-galerisi/3d-masaustu-resimler_468650.jpg") no-repeat;
        background-size: cover !important;
        -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
        -moz-background-size: cover !impoertant;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <img src='data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhFAAUAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAAUABQAAAIRhI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7rxUAOw=='
                 class="CanvasImg"/>
<h1>ALOOOU</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use  css:

```
body{height:100vh;
box-sizing:border-box;
overflow-y:hidden;}
```

CSS3 gives us viewport-relative units:

1. vh is relative to 1% of the height of the viewport ,using 100vh will cover the full screen.
2. using overflow-y
       hidden will remove horizontal scrolling
3. border-box indicates that the width and height properties (and
   min/max properties) includes content, padding and border, but not
   the margin